# Can LinqPad show my <summary> comments on properties from my custom EF lib?

Tags: linqpad

The Title already is the question.
In details: I'm using LinqPad 7/8 and I use it to inspect a database based on my own custom EF library which contains the entity classes. All properties are documented in xml style and a .xml output is created by the compiler in the same directory where the .dll is. But LinqPad doesn't display my property comment when I hover over a property name or a result column header. Is that not a supported feature? Do I need to configure something?

Thanks!

Comment: Hovering over a property works for me in the editor https://imgur.com/XHiJ2LI  , but not in the schema explorer or in the results tabs.

Comment: Your right @sgmoore. I wasn't aware that it works in the editor. I'm missing it in the results view most.

Comment: I just added a suggestion in the LinqPad forum.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, as @sgmoore pointed out, what I'm asking for is supported in the code editor  but not in the results view and not in the schema explorer. I files a suggestion for this with LinqPad.